# Describe normal distribution in layman terms

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

How would you describe a standard and normal distribution to someone with little knowledge of math?

I was thinking of explaining it through grades in a class.

Comment: Is this question a repeat?

Comment: Since only a mathematical description will be truly accurate, any other description will deal at most with some aspects of it. What is it about the normal distribution you want to convey and why? Why is the normal distribution an important thing to describe to someone without knowledge of mathematics?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a [Galton board](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaltonBoard.html) aka bean machine.

Some youtube links:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDIyAOBa_yU
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUgQtXEodf0

Answer (score 0):

One heuristic explanation of the central limit theorem is a good rationale for the normal distribution being a part of the pedagogy of statistics:

The normal distribution is a way of describing the errors that arise when you average up millions of unmeasured sources of variation in the thing you are trying to measure.